# Javascript - How can I set a value dynamically in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is this even possible?

```
<h3 id="question">Some text</h3>
```

...

```
var theQuestion = document.querySelector('#question').innerText;
...
self.newData.theQuestion = [];
```

Saves: `theKey : {"theQuestion":[]}`

Trying to achieve: `theKey : {"Some Text":[]}`

Edit: See screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not really get your purpose, The localstorage either the key or the value are just plain string, it can't be dynamically change it self.But you can redefine it or you can transform it when getting the value

Comment: Yes, you haven't understood the question. Look at the h3, the var 'theQuestion' and the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.. Didn't think it would be this easy:

```
self.newData[theQuestion]
```

Can close this question if you wish moderator.